# How do I use the quartz scheduler with Python?

Tags: python, quartz-scheduler

Is there a guide or tutorial on how to use the quartz Scheduler with Python.

Is there an existing API for Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that Quartz is a Java application/library, the simplest thing to do may be to run it within [Jython](http://jython.org).

Failing that, and if you simply want to control the configuration of jobs from Python, perhaps the [JDBC-JobStore](http://www.opensymphony.com/quartz/wikidocs/ConfigJobStoreTX.html) is of use, and you could write jobs into the database via Python. You'll still need an instance of Quartz running in a JVM. However, I'm not sure how well supported that is as a scenario.

Finally, you may be able to talk to a running Quartz instance via [JMX](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jmx.html). You'll need a JMX client, and consequently you'll need to spawn off a Java JMX client from your Python process.

I think (regrettably) there's a non-trivial mismatch between a Quartz instance (in Java) and your Python code.