# How to run a function using schedule in python

Tags: python, schedule

I want to run the following at a specific time. I looked around how to use this package, but somehow it does not work for me. Everythin in the function works fine, but when I want to combine it with schedule it does not work.

```
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
   import schedule
   import time
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
   from datetime import date




   def job():
   path = "C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe"
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
   driver.get("https://www.zssw.unibe.ch/usp/zms/angebot/5849/index_ger.html")  # link for 
   desired sport
   driver.maximize_window()
   wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
   pathanmelden = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,
                               value="//* 
   [@id='content']/section/div/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/a")
   pathanmelden.click()
   time.sleep(1)
   pathforstudents = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, 
   value="/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/input")
   pathforstudents.click()
   wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img#user_idp_iddicon"))).click()
   time.sleep(2)
   wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@title='Universitäten: Universität 
Bern']"))).click()
time.sleep(5)
clickanmelden = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//*[@id='wayf_submit_button']")
clickanmelden.click()
time.sleep(2)
emailadress = ""
password = ""
personaldataemail = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//*[@id='username']")
personaldataemail.send_keys(emailadress)
personaldatapass = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//*[@id='password']")
personaldatapass.send_keys(password)
clickanmelden2 = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//*[@id='login-button']")
clickanmelden2.click()
clickanmelden3 = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value = "//* 
[@id='form']/div[7]/div/div/button")
clickanmelden3.click()

schedule.every().seconds(10).do(job)

while True:
schedule.run_pending()
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail than "it does not work"?  Maybe the problem is your indentation.

Comment: Have you tried attaching the Python code to a task scheduler?

Comment: I'm sorry. I get the following error: TypeError: 'Job' object is not callable. I sue spyder and all packages should be installed correctly.

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn Yes, but it only opens the file. it does not run the code.

Comment: Does it provide an error or just a 0X1 error at runtime in the task scheduler?

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn task scheduler does throw an error it just does not execute the code, but as I said it opens the file at the time It should be executed.

Comment: @I created a batch file which contains the path of python and the script

Comment: somehow task scheduler did not work when I used pycharm. But now I saved the script with spyder and used the scheduler and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

My personal experience with such things has led me to always schedule such activities with a 3rd party app, for a very long time now: Quartz.

It really does take the guesswork out of a lot of things as it is a separate process from your intake and shaping of the data. Plus, as they have a Jython entrypoint, there aren't too many reasons to not at least try it....

If nothing else, it also insulates your scheduling activities from everything else about your process so that will make debugging easier.

[How do I use the quartz scheduler with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735266/how-do-i-use-the-quartz-scheduler-with-python)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).